Unrar reports "Total errors", but not what happend
I ran unrar x and at the end it reports Total errors: 4, but nothing else. I can see that the lines at the end have an 'OK' at the end, so I assume 4 of those will have 'ERROR' or similar... the problem is that I didn't run the command with grep (it was actually on a screen, so I don't even know if the console log file is an option...), I don't want to run the unrar again because the process last for hours, and for my sanity I don't want to manually scroll looking for those lines...
Is there any command I can use to get those 4 lines, re-try to unzip only the files that are not present (those 4 files), or to grep the already ran contents of a screen? Thanks.

I think I'll run the unrar again with the argument -o- to specify "ignore if exist", and then pipe the command to tee to make sure log the errors.
Edit: tee doesn't work properly with unrar, but as there are less messages it's fine to scroll.

You can try with unrar t (I'm not sure what it does exactly, but as per the man description it "tests" the archive's files), so maybe it could be of use. Otherwise possibly with p (which should just print the filenames) and scripting a solution that will test if filenames spit out by p exist or not. However it might be the case that those files have been extracted and that the errors are about something else.
